# css transition on horizontal & vertical scroll with jQuery detection

Tags: jquery, css

I've found a nice script to add and remove the class ".in-view" to an element on vertical scrolling. It worked fine, but I need to get this working for both – horizontal and vertical scrolling. This is the original script which worked fine for vertical scrolling:

```
var $animation_elements = jQuery('.animation-element');
var $window = jQuery(window);

function check_if_in_view() {
  var window_height = $window.height();
  var window_top_position = $window.scrollTop();
  var window_bottom_position = (window_top_position + window_height);


  jQuery.each($animation_elements, function() {
    var $element = jQuery(this);
    var element_height = $element.outerHeight();
    var element_top_position = $element.offset().top;
    var element_bottom_position = (element_top_position + element_height);

    //check to see if this current container is within viewport
    if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) &&
      (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {
      $element.addClass('in-view');
    } else {
      $element.removeClass('in-view');
    }
  });
}

$window.on('scroll resize', check_if_in_view);
$window.trigger('scroll');
```

and this is what I tried to make it work horizontally too, but unfortunately it didn't work:

```
var $animation_elements = jQuery('.animation-element');
var $window = jQuery(window);

function check_if_in_view() {
  var window_height = $window.height();
  var window_top_position = $window.scrollTop();
  var window_bottom_position = (window_top_position + window_height);

  var window_width = $window.width();
  var window_left_position = $window.scrollLeft();
  var window_right_position = (window_left_position + window_width);

  jQuery.each($animation_elements, function() {
    var $element = jQuery(this);
    var element_height = $element.outerHeight();
    var element_top_position = $element.offset().top;
    var element_bottom_position = (element_top_position + element_height);

    var element_width = $element.outerWidth();
    var element_left_position = $element.offset().left;
    var element_right_position = (element_left_position + element_width);

    //check to see if this current container is within viewport
    if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) &&
      (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {
      $element.addClass('in-view');
    } else if ((element_right_position >= window_left_position) &&
      (element_left_position <= window_right_position)) {
      $element.addClass('in-view');
    } else {
      $element.removeClass('in-view');
    }
  });
}

$window.on('scroll resize', check_if_in_view);
$window.trigger('scroll');
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: console reports no error. what I have recognized so far is, when I changed the script, the class ".in-view" isn't getting removed anymore once it was added.

Comment: Check your `if` and `else if` statements. The problem must be lying there.

Comment: thank you for the hint Rajan Benipuri, that was what i guessed too. but I couldn't find a clue so far.  i would really appreciate some additional help.